# Is there an API in OpenGL to draw a circle?

Tags: opengl

I found that when talking about drawing a circle, all examples I got is to use the basic API to compose a circle.

For example, iterator by degree and draw lines.

I was wondering if there's a 'built-in' version to draw a circle? As you can see, the iterator can be run parallel by using GPU, it seems faster.

What's more, can shader do this in a parallel way?

And, does this mean I have to write a shader to do this if I really care about the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in function, but you can indeed perform the loop on the GPU. That's exactly what [this article](https://open.gl/geometry) performs using a geometry shader, which looks like this:

```
#version 150 core

layout(points) in;
layout(line_strip, max_vertices = 64) out;

in vec3 vColor[];
in float vSides[];
out vec3 fColor;

const float PI = 3.1415926;

void main()
{
    fColor = vColor[0];

    // Safe, GLfloats can represent small integers exactly
    for (int i = 0; i <= vSides[0]; i++) {
        // Angle between each side in radians
        float ang = PI * 2.0 / vSides[0] * i;

        // Offset from center of point (0.3 to accomodate for aspect ratio)
        vec4 offset = vec4(cos(ang) * 0.3, -sin(ang) * 0.4, 0.0, 0.0);
        gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + offset;

        EmitVertex();
    }

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

You can see that each incoming vertex is transformed into a regular polygon around its position.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also wondering if there’s a library to do this?

Comment: @reavenisadesk I don't know of any, this is typically implemented as part of larger graphics frameworks.

Comment: I would suggest you to take look at GLu library source code is available you can ise functions like GluCylinder() to draw circles.

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni GLU performs GL1.2 immediate calls, which are not supported anymore.

Comment: Yes you can always convert the code to modern opengl.